# redirection of https page in apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

As it currently works. The endusers have to go the URL:

**https://cloud.olaf.europe.eu/owno**   and that works

but i want the users just to go to:

**https://cloud.olaf.europe.eu/** to access the page.

I now have in my httpd.conf on RedHat 6:

```
<Virtualhost *.80>
DocumenRoot /var/www/html/owno
ServerName olaf-owno.europe.eu
ServerAlias owno.olaf.europe.eu
</VirtualHost>
```

What do i have to add/modify to put this in practice ?

Johans

Comment: Please search before posting. http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteRule like the following. If I understood you correctly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/owno(.*) / [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an alias.

```
Example:
Alias /image /ftp/pub/image
<Directory /ftp/pub/image>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In your case you would use Alias / .....